# Update an in-progress Twilio call from a hard phone

Tags: twilio, twilio-api

I have a soft phone system set up and all is good. A call comes in to my soft phone, and I can put it on hold, transfer the call, etc. by clicking a button and sending a request to Twilio's REST API, or my server, or whatever it may be.

My question is, is it possible to update an in progress call if I am called on my SIP hard phone? What I want to do is, for example, during an in-progress call enter *1 to put the call on hold. Because it's a hard phone, I can't simply hit a button to make a request to my server.

I know I can use Gather to accept my input, but if I am on an in-progress call, how would I even initiate the Gather?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry this isn’t written all that well, doing on my phone.

It would be tough, as you need the callsid to initiate redirect. However, if you store your calls in Sync Lists, you could make a Function and have it either look up the phone number of the call and return the callsid to use in the redirect or enter the unique ID for the entry on the list.

Tie that function to a phone number, call via a your desk phone, put an if(event.digits) {obtain callsid from sync, then redirect, then callback() } else {do a gather() and don’t worry about the action url as you’ll just go to the top of this function but now you’ll have event.digits, then do your callback}            do not do a callback here or you’ll skip all of your above code}

Comment: Thanks for your response and pointing me towards Twilio Functions. That all makes sense, but the one thing I'm missing is how would I trigger the execution of the Twilio Function in mid-call?

Comment: Twilio Sales Engineer here.

As you've identified, you would need some sort of external trigger. This could be logic on your PBX that eventually makes an HTTP request to your API or a Twilio Function, but it could also be a button in a CRM/other relevant workspace. There's all sorts of stuff that you can do with tools like Twilio Sync to make this more seamless, but ultimately, you likely won't be able to use a SIP hardware phone's interface for fine-grained call control.